# Prove that if f $c$-concave function and $c(x,y) = |x-y|^2/2$, then $|x|^2/2 - f(x)$ is convex

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $c$ be a symmetric function. A function $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ is $c$-concave if there exists a function $g$ such that
$$f = \inf_y \left\{ c(x,y) - g(y) \right\}.
$$

Now, let $c(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|^2}{2}$. How does one then prove that if $f$ is $c$-concave,
then $h(x) = \frac{|x|^2}{2}-f(x)$ is convex? I saw this assertion in a book, but I've not been able to prove it.

Comment: What is $g$?  If you replace the inf by a sup then convexity is clear. Can you name your source? Maybe there is a typo?

Comment: $g$ is just an arbitrary function. The definition of $c$-concave functions is that it is equal to the $c$-transform of another function.

Comment: @DaviBarreira does my edit correctly phrase your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plugging in the formula for $f$, you get:
\begin{align}
h(x) &= \sup_y \left\{ 0.5x^2 - 0.5(x-y)^2 + g(y) \right\} \\
&= \sup_y \left\{ xy - 0.5y^2 + g(y) \right\}.
\end{align}
The supremum of affine functions is convex.